# Changing the length of a circle SVG stroke programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I created a circle in Inkscape and switched off the fill so that only the stroke is visible and also made the starting point 45 degrees and the ending point 315 degrees.

I then rotated it 90 degrees and this is the end result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
<svg width="300" height="300" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 79.375 79.375" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <path transform="rotate(90)" d="m64.961-15.355a34.984 34.412 0 0 1-49.474 1e-6 34.984 34.412 0 0 1-1e-6 -48.666 34.984 34.412 0 0 1 49.474-2e-6" fill="none" opacity=".55814" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="10.583"/>
</svg>
```

And it renders like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
<svg width="300" height="300" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 79.375 79.375" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <path transform="rotate(90)" d="m64.961-15.355a34.984 34.412 0 0 1-49.474 1e-6 34.984 34.412 0 0 1-1e-6 -48.666 34.984 34.412 0 0 1 49.474-2e-6" fill="none" opacity=".55814" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="10.583"/>
</svg>
```

I want to be able to overlay a copy and control the length of the stroke starting at the bottom left corner.  So for example display only 22% of the total length of the overlay or display the segment from the 315 degree end point to 255.60 degrees?

How would we go about this (Effectively programmatically doing the inkscape start and end controls)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following snippet takes a percentage as input and then computes the parameters of the [elliptical arc curve command](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands) `A` in the `<path>` element. 100% corresponds to a three-quarter-arc.

```js
var path = document.getElementById("path");
function draw(v) {
  var theta = v * Math.PI * 0.015;
  var large = theta <= Math.PI ? 0 : 1;
  path.setAttribute("d", `M1,0 A1,1 0 ${large} 1 ${Math.cos(theta)},${Math.sin(theta)}`);
}
```

```html
<svg width="150" height="150" viewBox="-1.2 -1.2 2.4 2.4"
  transform="rotate(135)">
 <path d="M1,0 A1,1 0 1 1 0,-1"
   fill="none" opacity=".55814"
   stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round"
   stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width=".25"/>
 <path id="path"
   fill="none"
   stroke="red" stroke-linecap="round"
   stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width=".1"/>
</svg>
<form onsubmit="draw(this.v.value); return false;">
  <input name="v"/>%
  <input type="submit" value="Draw"/>
</form>
```

(After reading myf's answer, it became clear that you want *two* arcs in total. I have adapted my code accordingly, but the idea remains basically the same.)

Comment: WOW!!!  Just WOWWWWAAA!!  Amazingly brilliant answer!!!  Thanks so much!!!  You guys rock!!

Answer (score 5):

Probably easiest way would be to use [`pathLength` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength) like:

```
pathlength="100" stroke-dasharray="10 100"
```

Altering the the first value of the [`stroke-dasharray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) would express the "percentage" (`10` in above example makes it occupy 10% of the total length). Moving that segment along the path is possible thanks negative [`stroke-dashoffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dashoffset). Funky perk of this approach is that it can be used for "tracing" any compact path:

```html
<body bgcolor="darkslategray" text="snow">
Length:
<input id="l" type="range" value="10" max="80" 
oninput="p.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', value + ' 100');
 o.max = 100 - value; nextElementSibling.value = value;
"> <output>10</output><br>
Offset:
<input id="o" type="range" value="20" max="90" 
oninput="p.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', - value);
 l.max = 100 - value; nextElementSibling.value = value;
"> <output>20</output><br>
<svg width="300" height="150" viewBox="0 0 80 80" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round"
stroke="#000" stroke-width="10">
 <path d="M13 66 A 35 35 0 1 1 65 65 A 10 10 1 1 1 40 45 A 7 7 1 1 0 25 35" />
 <path d="M13 66 A 35 35 0 1 1 65 65 A 10 10 1 1 1 40 45 A 7 7 1 1 0 25 35" 
 id="p"
 stroke="#F99"
 stroke-width="4"
 pathlength="100.1"
 stroke-dashoffset="-20"
 stroke-dasharray="10 1000"
/></svg>
<!--
* 100.1 pathlength value is to keep zero length "dot" at the final 100 offset
* 1000 array "gap" value is here just to be sure; any value greater or equal pathlength should do.
-->
```

Comment: WOW!!!  Just WOWWWWAAA!!  Amazingly brilliant answer!!!  THANK YOU!!!